# Olympus Airで撮影した画像から位置情報を取得したい

Tags: android, olympus-camerakit, gps, exif

Olympus Airで撮影する時に、OLYCamera クラスのsetGeolocation()でスマホの位置情報を撮影画像のExifにセットすることは出来たのですが、

次に、セットした位置情報を含む撮影画像をOlympus Airからダウンロードするときに位置情報を取得したくて、OLYCamera クラスinquireContentInformation()でExif情報を取得したのですが、含まれるTAGで位置情報に関連しそうなのは、
・LocationStatus
・Location
でした。
LocationStatusはExifに位置情報が含まれているか否かが取得でき、
Locationは常に「0x00」がセットされていました。

setGeolocation()でセットした緯度経度はExifビューワで確認していますし、Windowsのファイルプロパティの詳細情報でも確認済です。

何か他に緯度経度を取得する方法がありましたら、ご教授いただきたくよろしくお願い致します。

OSはAndroid 4.4.4です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

iOS版のSDKで色々と試してみたところではAndroid版も同じだと思いますが、`downloadImage(path, resize, callback)`を使って一番小さい画像などをダウンロードしてそのExif(正確にはGPS IFD)を自力で読むしかないのではないか、という気がします。

2015-07-28 追記
全てのEXIF情報が取れそうなのは、`downloadContentThumbnail()`でも`downloadContentScreennail()`でもなく、どうやら`downloadImage()`の完了時に呼び出される`DownloadImageCallback`の`onCompleted()`の引数`data`のようです。

Comment: 早速のご回答誠にありがとうございます。 実は、inquireContentInformation()を試す前に downloadContentScreennail()のコールバックで受け取った Map<String, Object> metadata から緯度経度を取ろうとしてうまくいかなかったという経緯があります。 うまくいかないというのは、 ・mapからとりだすKeyを調べて試すもとれない。 ・デバッガーで見る限りValueが入っていない？ という感じで挫折してしまいました、、、 もし、metaデータの緯度経度のKeyをご存知でしたら教えていただけますと助かります。

Comment: 確かにmetadataは空っぽらしいので(しかもiOS版にはない引数)、もう一方のdataを一時ファイルに保存してそれを`ExifInterface`クラスで読み込んでみるのはどうでしょうか。dataの方は多分EXIFギッシリのJPEGファイルそのものだと思います。

Comment: EXIFがちゃんと取れそうなAPIがわかったので回答に追記しました。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます！
試してみます。